# Angularjs OrderBy Filter Parameter contains "-"

Tags: angularjs, parameters, filter, sql-order-by

I need help on angularjs filter.

`$filter('orderBy')($scope.contactlist, '+contact-firstname')`

This filter works fine when orderby parameter does not containing `-`.
But it doesn't work when it contains `-` like `contact-firstname`. 
Anybody please help me!!!

Comment: can you provide a fiddle demonstrating this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to use an array as the second parameter of $filter.

As it's written now, you are ordering your list according to their property "contact-firstname" in an ascending order.

For ordering by "contact" ascending and by firstname descending in case of contact equality, you have to write it as

```
$filter('orderBy')($scope.contactlist, ['+contact','-firstname'])
```

I've made a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKH63/) explaining your issue

Comment: Thank you. I also want to do this way, but the api is fixed and I can not touch it.